# Jquery floating animation issue

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to do an animation.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pVTR7/9/

```
$('a.hide').click(function(){
    $('.left').animate({'width':'0%'}, 1000);    
    $('.right').animate({'width':'100%'}, 1000);
});

$('a.reset').click(function(){
    $('.left').animate({'width':'50%'}, 1000);    
    $('.right').animate({'width':'50%'}, 1000);
});
```

Desc: 2 different areas with different content at 50% width.  When clicking on 'Click' the left area will hide and the right one will take full width. When click 'Reset' the left area will be slided in and both areas will be 50% width. (see demo)

**Problem**: When hiding the left area the right area jumps down during the animation!!
On Reset everything works fine witout any space between both areas (like it should be)

Depending on browser there are some different handling.
Safari -> Right area jumps down.
Firefox -> Space between areas

I could use absolute position, but then i would need to always check the hight of the content and to add this height to the container.

Comment: so you want the same animation effect how it is happening for the reset right?

Comment: You need to change method. Floats are difficult to control

Comment: I managed to control the floats and do what this guy wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$('a.hide').click(function(){
    var the_width = $(this).parent().width();
    $('.left').animate({'width':the_width-the_width}, 1000);    
    $('.right').animate({'width':the_width}, 1000);
});

$('a.reset').click(function(){
    var the_width = $(this).parent().width() / 2;
    $('.left').animate({'width':the_width }, 1000);    
    $('.right').animate({'width': the_width}, 1000);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/raghurocks/pVTR7/18/

You should not give the direct values when you are using the floating it is better to give using the variables
Hope this helps D:

Answer (score 0):

Here's the deal:

http://jsfiddle.net/pVTR7/19/

I needed to change the width to reduce to 0, and not 0%

```
$('a.hide').click(function(){
    $('.left').animate({'width':'0'}, 1000);    
    $('.right').animate({'width':'100%'}, 1000);
});
```

.right had to be set to float:left;

```
.right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Hope this helps!